# Animations in visual state do not animate (WinRT)

Tags: c#, animation, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am developing on Windows 8.1 RTM. I have a custom control with a custom dependency property of type double. This control has been placed in a user control. I am calling VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, true) on the user control. The animation should transition for 2 seconds. However, it simply snaps from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0. The callback function is only called with either 0 or 1. If I directly set the dependency property to any value between 0 and 1, it works as expected.

I have the following XAML:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:controls="using:MyControls" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="TestStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
              <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:2"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="A">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                        Duration="0"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MyControl1"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="MyDependencyProperty"
                        To="0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="B">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                        Duration="0"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MyControl1"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="MyDependencyProperty"
                        To="1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <controls:MyControl x:Name="MyControl1" MyDependencyProperty="0">
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If I set the target property to Opacity, it works.

Looking at previous questions, EnableDependentAnimation seems to be the common culprit for this behavior, but I've already set it to true.

Timeline.AllowDependentAnimations is true.

I've stripped the control down to just the one dependency property with no logic in the callback. Same issue.

Answer (score 1):

See i was going through the animation on dependency property and found an intereting point I thought I should share

To be animated, the animation's target property must be a dependency property. Also, to be animated, the target property's value type must be supported by one of the existing [Timeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.aspx)-derived animation types. When an animation is applied and running, the animated value operates at a higher precedence than any value (such as a local value) that the property otherwise has. Animations also have an optional HoldEnd behavior that can cause animations to apply to property values even if the animation visually appears to be stopped.

I dont know may be This will help Here's the link to the documentation

[animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700353.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the information but none of it is relevant to my question.

Comment: I know this is response is old however, provided useful information. Thanks. Definatly worth noting WinRT custom dependency properties should use DiscreteObjectKeyFrame to animate. Thanks :)