# No pauses between Visual State changes in VS 2013/Blend animation?

Tags: c#, animation, winrt-xaml, expression-blend

UPDATE: I have put together a test project that shows the problem.  Here is the download link:

http://robodance.com/blend/roschler-blend-animation-problem.zip

I have an animation that I created with Expression Blend 2013 for a Windows Store app (WinRT/Metro).  I set the Default Transition time to 1 second.  However, when I run the app and trigger the animation, the states are played one right after each other without a 1 second intervening delay.

I found this thread but as far as I know all of the properties I am working with are dependency properties.  When I click on each state in Blend, I do see the desired changes:

[Animations in visual state do not animate (WinRT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991200/animations-in-visual-state-do-not-animate-winrt)

Another strange issue is that Transition Preview doesn't work in Blend.  I turn it on and when I click on the initial state or any other state, nothing happens.

Why am I having problems with my animation state transitions and what can I do to fix it?  Below is the XAML that was generated for the Visual States.  As you can see, the GeneratedDuration properties all show a delay of 1 second (00:00:01).

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
            <VisualTransition From="CountdownStart" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" To="TMinus2"/>
            <VisualTransition From="TMinus2" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" To="TMinus1"/>
            <VisualTransition From="TMinus1" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" To="LiftOff"/>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="CountdownStart">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="stackListHolder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RangeBase.Value)" Storyboard.TargetName="progressBar" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCancelSearch">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCancelSearch" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="TMinus2">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="66" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RangeBase.Value)" Storyboard.TargetName="progressBar" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCancelSearch">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCancelSearch" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="TMinus1">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="stackListHolder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="33" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RangeBase.Value)" Storyboard.TargetName="progressBar" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCancelSearch">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="btnCancelSearch" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="LiftOff">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RangeBase.Value)" Storyboard.TargetName="progressBar" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
<Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <EntranceThemeTransition/>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

It irritates me that this does not work. For the time being, I have a solution for you that simply removes the ProgressBar from the equation. It might take a while for me to figure out the other.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="EmptyState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="FullState">
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="HalfState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-250" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Button Content="Empty" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="20,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="EmptyState"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Full" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="367,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="FullState"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Half" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="194,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156">
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="HalfState"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" Margin="23,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Background="Red">
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,500,50" />
        </Grid.Clip>            
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

The answer to this type of thing is one of two typical answers. 1) it is really easy and simply a misunderstanding by us or 2) it's not working like it should. I don't know which yet.

Best of luck.

Comment: Well at least it didn't work for you either so I don't feel dumb.  Thanks for checking it out and for the substitute XAML code.

Comment: That sub code is probably better anyway. It's so lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to look at the difference between mine, that works, and yours:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualState0"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualState1">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="90" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="408.468" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="245" Margin="179,172,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="256" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

I think you need to simplify and post a little more.

Comment: I have added a download link to a VS2013 project that illustrates the problem.